# how to use order by based on strings in sqlite

Tags: sqlite

i have a dataset in sqlite db which has ids and image urls. It is as follows:

```
ID  |   URL
1   |   http://img.url1.com
2   |       
3   |   http://img.url2.com
4   |   http://img.url3.com
5   |   http://img.url4.com
6   |   
7   |   http://img.url5.com
8   |   
9   |   http://img.url6.com
10  |   
11  |   http://img.url7.com
12  |   http://img.url8.com
13  |
```

I want to sort this accordingly in such a way that the ids with blank values appears at the bottom and the ids with nearest with img urls get appeared at the top with nearest values in the sorted order of ids as follows:

```
ID  |   URL
1   |   http://img.url1.com
3   |   http://img.url2.com
4   |   http://img.url3.com
5   |   http://img.url4.com
7   |   http://img.url5.com
9   |   http://img.url6.com
11  |   http://img.url7.com
12  |   http://img.url8.com
2   |       
6   |   
8   |   
10  |   
13  |
```

Can you suggest me what kind of query I need to put ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM T
ORDER BY (URL IS NULL),id
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/65740/2)</kbd>

Comment: @LS_dev Thanks. Parenthesis aren't for Slqlite but for a programmer :)